# Identifier 'name' is not defined. 'object' does not contain such a member

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm creating an app using angular + ionic. In the app users can set up accounts and very other peoples accounts. I'm displaying other user accounts on one page but when I try to display the current users account on their own page I am getting this error:
[image]

Can someone help me out with this error, please?
The issue is when I try to call relevantArtist.name on the tab4 page

tabs.page.ts:

```
export class Tab4Page implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  loadedArtist: Artist[];
  relevantArtist: Artist[];
  isLoading = false;

  private artistSub: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private artistService: ArtistService,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.artistSub = this.artistService.artist.subscribe(artist => {
      this.loadedArtist = artist;
      this.relevantArtist = this.loadedArtist;
      this.loadedArtist = this.relevantArtist.slice(1);
      this.authService.userId.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(userId => {
        this.relevantArtist = this.loadedArtist.filter(
          artist => artist.userId === userId
        );
      });
    });
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.artistService.fetchArtist().subscribe(() => {
      this.isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.artistSub) {
      this.artistSub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

}
```

tag4.page.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <!-- add menuId to have different menus -->
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      <ion-title>{{ isLoading ? 'Loading...' : relevantArtist.name }}</ion-title>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>

<ion-content>


</ion-content>
```

tabs-routing.module.ts:

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/tab1.module').then(m => m.Tab1PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'discover/:artistId',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/discover/artist-details/artist-details.module').then(m => m.ArtistDetailsPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'discover-venue/:venueId',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/discover/venue-details/venue-details.module').then(m => m.VenueDetailsPageModule)
      }
    ]
  },

      {
        path: 'tab4',
        children: [
          {
            path: ':artistId',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab4/tab4.module').then(m => m.Tab4PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'edit/:artistId',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab4/edit-page/edit-page-routing.module').then(m => m.EditPagePageRoutingModule)
      }
    ]
  },
```

The information that it's calling on is located in a service that uses firebase. The other pages have no issues at all and I'm very confused as to why this one does.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that `relevantArtist` is an array of `Artist` not the object `Artist`. The [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function creates a new array that passes the condition set.

Looking at your implementation it seems that the "current user" will always be a single instance of `Artist`.

One solution, always assuming that the userId is unique, is to simply get the element 0 of that array.

```
<ion-title>{{ isLoading ? 'Loading...' : relevantArtist[0].name }}</ion-title>
```

Another, more elegant solution, always assuming that `userId` is unique for each artist is to use the function [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of filter, this way you will get a single `Artist`.

You would need to do the following changes on your code to add a new variable to store the current user information:

```
...
// Artist[] => Artist
currentArtist: Artist;
...
// filter => find
this.currentArtist = this.loadedArtist.find(artist => artist.userId === userId);
```

Also could create a pipe to do use `find` directly on the template.

**find.pipe.ts**

```
import {
    Injector,
    Pipe,
    PipeTransform
} from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'find'
})
export class FindPipe implements PipeTransform {

    public constructor(private readonly injector: Injector) {
    }

    transform(value: Array<any>, callback: any): any {
        return value.find(callback);
    }
}
```

In your .ts, add the filter function

```
findCurrentUser(artist: Artist): boolean {
  return artist.userId === userId;
}
```

In your tab4.page.html

```
<ion-title>
  {{ isLoading ? 'Loading...' : relevantArtist.name | find: findCurrentUser}}
</ion-title>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I gave this a try and its giving me more errors. I have artist as an array in my service so it says its missing the following properties(then lists all properties in the array)

Comment: @mcadam4000 I see how my answer could be confusing. I edited it to make it more clear. Also I added other possible solutions. If you could create a codepen or jsfiddle so we can reproduce the issue would allow for better and more detailed answers.

Comment: So when I change my code to this : '<ion-title>{{ isLoading ? 'Loading...' : relevantArtist[0].name }}</ion-title>' I no longer have errors in my code accept when I run it and click on that tab I get the console error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"
I feel that the issue now lies in my tab-routing.module but when I try to fix it it's still not working. I've updated the code to show my routing module

Comment: This is most likley due `relevantArtist` being an empty array. `[][0].name => undefined`. You need to take into account this.
- Your `isLoading` variable is true only when the subscribers are resolved

- To take into account that the `userId` does not have a match inside `loadedArtist` that will return an empty array **This could be the issue you are facing**.

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite the code to wait for all suscriptions to complete before setting loading to false.

```
ngOnInit() {
}

ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  
  this.artistSub = this.artistService.artist.subscribe(artist => {
    this.loadedArtist = artist;
    this.relevantArtist = this.loadedArtist;
    this.loadedArtist = this.relevantArtist.slice(1);
    this.authService.userId.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(userId => {
      this.relevantArtist = this.loadedArtist.find(
        artist => artist.userId === userId
      );

      this.isLoading = false;
    });
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this.artistSub) {
    this.artistSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

> Also I would consider refactoring your subscription code because it's kinda confusing assigning different types into the same variable

Comment: I gave this a try and the error I'm getting now is as follows: Type 'Artist' is missing the following properties from type 'Artist[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
Any idea why this is happening and how I might fix it?